# Is $\frac{d \sin\theta}{d \theta} \big|_{\theta=0} = 1$ a consequence of the geometrical definition of $\sin\theta \equiv \frac{opp}{hyp}$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, trigonometry

> Is $\dfrac{d \sin\theta}{d \theta} \big|_{\theta=0} = 1$ a consequence of the geometrical definition of $\sin\theta \equiv \dfrac{opp}{hyp}$?

I do not know whether $\dfrac{d \sin\theta}{d \theta} \big|_{\theta=0} = 1$ is an additional constraint on the sine function or not.

Comment: Do you know the $\cos$ function?

Comment: Very Intersting question. It's my belif that we should need other constraint because there can be many f such that Df(0)=1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1)

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not.

Comment: Since $$\begin{align}\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\sin(\theta)\right|_{\theta=0} &=\lim_{\theta\to0}\frac{\sin(\theta)-\sin(0)}{\theta-0}\\ &=\lim_{\theta\to0}\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\theta}\\&=1
\end{align}$$ Martin R's comment does seem relevant. There is also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/282041) that might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{d \sin\theta}{d \theta} \big|_{\theta=0} = \lim _{h \to 0} \dfrac{\sin(0+h) - \sin(0)}h
\\ \;  \\ \;
\\= \lim _{h \to 0} \dfrac{\sin(h) }h
$$
The geometric definition of $\sin(h)$ allows us to set up the inequality
$$| \sin(h)| \le |h|\le |\tan(h)|  $$
($h$ is in radians)
now dividing through by $| \sin(h)|$ ...
$$1\le \bigg | \dfrac{ h}{ \sin(h)}  \bigg |  \le |\sec(h)|  $$
So by the squeeze theorem we have
$$\lim _{h \to 0} \bigg | \dfrac{ h}{ \sin(h)}  \bigg | =1$$
Hopefully you can take it from here